# How to replace a row in GScript (Google Sheet) if a column value matches another sheet column value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to update or replace the contents in a row in PasteSheet if Column B contains a value that matches another value in CopySheet Column B. The matching row in Copysheet is copied to update the row in PasteSheet. Column Values are numbers i.e 4.0

Here's the code I've been working on, but nothing is happening.

```
function timestamp(){

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("IMPORT");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard");

  var lastRow = copySheet.getLastRow()
  var lastRow2 = pasteSheet.getLastRow()

  for (var i = 1; i <= lastRow2; i++){

    // pastesheet values

    var pasteRange = pasteSheet.getRange([i], 2);
    var pasteValues = pasteRange.getValues();

    var newRange = pasteSheet.getRange([i], 1,1,41);
    var newValues = newRange.getValues();

    for (var u = 1; u <= lastRow; u++){

    // copysheet values

    var copyRange = copySheet.getRange([u], 2);
    var copyValues = copyRange.getValues();

    var upRange = copySheet.getRange([u], 1,1,41);
    var upValues = upRange.getValues();

    if (copyValues == pasteValues){ // 
      newRange.setValue(upValues);

      }
    }
    }
}
```

Any help to fix this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updating Dashboard rows from Import Sheet that match with Dates in column B**

```
//V8
function updateMatching() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const srcsr=4;
  const dessr=4;
  const srcsh=ss.getSheetByName('IMPORT');
  const srcrg=srcsh.getRange(srcsr,1,srcsh.getLastRow()-srcsr+1,srcsh.getLastColumn());
  const srcvA=srcrg.getValues();
  const dessh=ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  const desrg=dessh.getRange(dessr,1,dessh.getLastRow()-dessr+1,dessh.getLastColumn());
  const desvA=desrg.getValues();
  var oA=desvA;
  srcvA.forEach(function(sr,i){
    desvA.forEach(function(dr,j){
      if(sr[1]==dr[1]) {
        oA[j]=srcvA[i];
        dessh.getRange(dessr + j,1,1,dessh.getLastColumn()).setBackground("#ffff00");//Changed the background just highlight the updates.  You can remove this.
      }
    });
  });
  desrg.setValues(oA);
}


//Pre V8 - not much change.  I'm still learning es6 so if you want to offer suggestions to that end I'm open to them.
function updateMatching1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcsr=4;
  var dessr=4;
  var srcsh=ss.getSheetByName('IMPORT');
  var srcrg=srcsh.getRange(srcsr,1,srcsh.getLastRow()-srcsr+1,srcsh.getLastColumn());
  var srcvA=srcrg.getValues();
  var dessh=ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  var desrg=dessh.getRange(dessr,1,dessh.getLastRow()-dessr+1,dessh.getLastColumn());
  var desvA=desrg.getValues();
  srcvA.forEach(function(sr,i){
    desvA.forEach(function(dr,j){
      if(sr[1]==dr[1]) {
        desvA[j]=srcvA[i];
        dessh.getRange(dessr + j,1,1,dessh.getLastColumn()).setBackground("#ffff00")
      }
    });
  });
  desrg.setValues(desvA);
}
```

IMPORT Sheet Start Data(csv):

```
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
HDR1,HDR2,HDR3,HDR4,HDR5,HDR6,HDR7,HDR8,HDR9,HDR10,HDR11,HDR12,HDR13,HDR14,HDR15,HDR16,HDR17,HDR18,HDR19,HDR20,HDR21,HDR22,HDR23,HDR24,HDR25,HDR26,HDR27,HDR28,HDR29,HDR30,HDR31,HDR32,HDR33,HDR34,HDR35,HDR36,HDR37,HDR38,HDR39,HDR40,HDR41
Fri Jan 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),1,1,2,1,2,0,2,5,5,4,10,11,11,12,9,5,8,17,18,19,1,1,12,11,9,16,6,26,14,19,15,25,16,0,29,31,20,4,23,0
Sat Feb 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),3,0,2,4,4,4,6,0,7,4,2,12,9,6,7,16,10,16,17,19,3,3,17,23,23,18,12,17,3,28,27,0,2,18,16,0,11,14,32,6
Sun Feb 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),5,2,3,5,1,0,5,6,10,7,3,9,7,6,8,4,9,2,18,4,22,14,5,25,0,12,25,7,12,29,4,3,10,8,31,17,38,28,21,39
Mon Feb 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),7,1,4,4,7,1,0,4,0,9,9,14,3,5,16,7,7,9,3,8,13,13,0,22,24,14,20,6,20,16,5,19,11,31,3,14,19,34,26,36
Tue Feb 04 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),9,4,2,4,6,0,3,10,9,1,14,11,6,10,9,3,4,12,11,23,21,14,21,27,6,10,10,28,13,7,14,16,29,10,14,33,32,37,10,25
Wed Feb 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),11,6,1,3,9,8,9,8,1,1,6,5,2,11,15,5,1,4,22,24,11,24,0,28,7,5,18,20,13,7,33,25,21,34,4,12,40,13,24,14
Thu Feb 06 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),13,2,8,5,4,4,11,13,3,5,10,8,3,18,19,21,0,23,6,20,2,24,19,4,26,21,6,1,17,0,17,18,32,16,21,38,3,24,37,29
Fri Feb 07 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),15,4,1,3,8,0,11,11,5,14,2,11,17,2,14,3,16,4,19,23,2,2,18,20,11,9,20,29,13,7,5,26,39,3,5,1,15,6,23,4
Sat Feb 08 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),17,2,9,2,8,3,9,11,16,0,4,9,6,19,16,6,7,3,3,18,2,4,26,13,29,31,8,23,22,8,38,0,2,10,3,34,12,4,41,34
Sun Feb 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),19,0,1,0,3,2,8,3,15,8,18,17,13,20,6,11,4,7,16,2,12,13,4,30,30,8,14,36,32,27,0,6,5,26,35,39,0,39,42,28
Mon Feb 10 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),14,9,8,2,14,14,1,11,4,0,2,12,13,13,2,12,23,8,28,14,1,23,18,33,33,7,17,12,16,21,24,5,20,12,29,39,3,28,28,26
Tue Feb 11 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),23,5,11,1,2,7,7,12,3,14,2,9,2,5,21,17,5,6,6,14,31,20,28,9,33,29,1,24,7,6,6,3,32,39,45,45,33,12,18,47
Wed Feb 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),16,7,14,12,16,17,10,17,20,9,21,3,5,25,23,5,8,25,9,21,6,25,8,15,24,22,12,33,25,35,4,27,21,13,24,5,37,37,14,4
Thu Feb 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),27,1,0,9,7,3,13,9,5,6,15,2,10,8,14,14,20,12,31,15,14,34,22,9,5,12,4,5,30,2,2,28,44,9,19,17,15,46,10,8
Fri Feb 14 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),29,4,5,4,7,6,16,10,15,21,19,10,8,7,11,29,28,6,14,11,23,1,3,8,31,3,7,37,19,4,18,32,9,5,44,32,28,8,26,26
Sat Feb 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),31,14,3,6,2,13,18,12,1,13,23,12,3,2,10,2,2,25,1,20,11,5,0,21,10,12,22,23,15,0,4,19,37,1,23,44,1,17,52,4
Sun Feb 16 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),33,15,12,12,6,6,11,12,3,17,18,12,3,26,4,16,24,3,3,2,29,8,23,37,36,15,26,36,8,34,46,43,44,40,1,34,8,5,0,14
Mon Feb 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),35,12,2,11,21,13,23,19,25,8,17,28,5,4,7,6,17,2,4,16,7,18,28,18,12,9,6,32,38,1,44,35,12,31,35,5,7,33,22,41
Tue Feb 18 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),37,3,7,9,14,4,24,17,15,1,16,0,25,26,18,3,7,16,1,22,34,39,40,2,23,19,1,6,15,9,33,35,18,8,33,38,8,13,37,37
Wed Feb 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),39,10,7,9,5,2,21,9,5,13,16,27,27,20,7,9,30,7,21,17,11,35,0,31,38,39,6,22,43,5,30,15,38,23,49,43,25,43,5,45
```

Dashboard Sheet Starting Data(csv):

```
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
HDR1,HDR2,HDR3,HDR4,HDR5,HDR6,HDR7,HDR8,HDR9,HDR10,HDR11,HDR12,HDR13,HDR14,HDR15,HDR16,HDR17,HDR18,HDR19,HDR20,HDR21,HDR22,HDR23,HDR24,HDR25,HDR26,HDR27,HDR28,HDR29,HDR30,HDR31,HDR32,HDR33,HDR34,HDR35,HDR36,HDR37,HDR38,HDR39,HDR40,HDR41
Fri Jan 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),2,0,0,0,4,3,0,5,1,9,7,9,0,8,10,12,0,8,9,7,0,10,3,5,1,24,25,0,20,6,27,26,8,0,31,34,26,3,12,29
Sat Feb 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),4,2,3,3,0,5,0,5,6,0,7,6,12,0,3,14,5,3,17,11,2,15,2,23,7,9,13,3,2,20,4,1,24,2,31,5,33,27,29,30
Sun Feb 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),6,1,1,3,0,0,4,4,0,6,9,6,12,14,12,4,4,3,5,18,7,20,8,6,13,27,22,21,4,12,3,8,8,7,19,18,15,8,29,3
Mon Feb 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),8,2,1,3,3,8,3,6,2,7,5,8,11,7,15,14,11,19,20,3,19,13,20,1,16,21,10,10,5,15,22,14,31,11,25,24,15,23,11,17
Tue Feb 04 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),10,2,5,5,4,6,3,11,6,2,0,13,13,10,13,4,5,1,8,5,13,3,25,13,9,17,30,21,27,10,6,15,3,2,29,19,14,16,13,38
Wed Feb 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),12,1,4,2,8,4,5,3,6,7,8,14,17,18,9,13,21,8,10,5,17,2,7,12,14,15,29,5,17,10,16,8,8,6,22,20,23,8,41,35
Thu Feb 06 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),14,2,8,9,5,4,3,6,7,12,9,9,1,7,8,15,14,21,2,9,9,11,23,19,3,0,27,27,27,4,36,13,9,23,11,38,23,17,5,40
Fri Feb 07 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),16,3,2,0,1,10,0,2,15,4,17,5,11,6,18,3,4,9,20,12,2,11,25,19,16,12,26,0,21,33,30,17,10,16,1,39,15,6,13,5
Sat Feb 08 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),18,6,7,6,8,1,5,11,13,2,13,3,1,5,21,9,24,20,14,19,5,4,0,23,27,5,13,7,17,10,9,28,24,1,29,28,42,18,28,14
Sun Feb 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),20,8,2,0,2,7,2,7,2,14,17,2,2,2,7,2,18,1,14,7,4,6,25,4,10,17,34,36,2,19,13,27,22,23,36,3,16,42,7,16
Mon Feb 10 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),14,4,1,8,14,0,7,15,5,9,18,8,1,5,8,3,15,10,2,10,16,18,17,11,0,7,19,1,33,12,38,20,9,9,33,5,4,43,3,27
Tue Feb 11 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),24,7,6,12,7,14,5,1,14,1,14,8,2,15,0,25,2,0,2,25,6,24,18,26,8,10,25,21,33,10,27,15,33,30,36,39,38,15,46,9
Wed Feb 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),16,9,0,5,1,2,17,5,18,16,18,17,8,17,0,12,11,4,5,27,5,9,24,21,22,19,3,32,24,12,9,33,19,5,5,1,6,48,43,50
Thu Feb 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),28,5,13,15,13,4,5,1,14,0,17,6,18,17,19,4,6,22,21,30,15,6,11,34,10,32,19,20,29,16,32,42,38,26,37,19,20,4,38,25
Fri Feb 14 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),30,5,12,13,1,1,7,13,19,13,3,17,4,16,15,14,6,11,12,11,0,11,33,28,4,13,1,2,22,4,40,37,24,27,41,19,22,19,8,24
Sat Feb 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),32,15,12,10,5,15,8,21,6,2,0,9,8,0,28,21,26,13,9,30,3,17,6,8,14,28,36,28,30,41,26,46,36,22,13,39,5,10,21,12
Sun Feb 16 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),34,10,6,3,1,17,18,11,19,8,9,7,20,20,18,27,21,30,25,12,10,25,14,37,20,32,15,10,23,5,3,0,48,13,26,14,6,39,34,27
Mon Feb 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),36,15,7,19,5,15,17,20,4,19,22,15,24,19,29,3,21,15,12,23,14,11,32,14,10,39,31,24,45,37,29,3,15,22,44,52,52,38,7,47
Tue Feb 18 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),38,3,0,21,18,19,21,2,1,10,6,15,5,7,29,12,16,28,31,8,5,30,36,1,35,28,8,21,1,9,33,32,24,22,34,51,25,12,36,9
Wed Feb 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),40,6,13,3,19,0,18,8,10,25,6,19,27,8,7,15,35,32,2,25,21,3,25,38,20,12,31,20,6,4,5,49,29,37,50,22,51,21,1,13
```

Dashboard Data after running script(csv):

```
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
HDR1,HDR2,HDR3,HDR4,HDR5,HDR6,HDR7,HDR8,HDR9,HDR10,HDR11,HDR12,HDR13,HDR14,HDR15,HDR16,HDR17,HDR18,HDR19,HDR20,HDR21,HDR22,HDR23,HDR24,HDR25,HDR26,HDR27,HDR28,HDR29,HDR30,HDR31,HDR32,HDR33,HDR34,HDR35,HDR36,HDR37,HDR38,HDR39,HDR40,HDR41
Fri Jan 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),2,0,0,0,4,3,0,5,1,9,7,9,0,8,10,12,0,8,9,7,0,10,3,5,1,24,25,0,20,6,27,26,8,0,31,34,26,3,12,29
Sat Feb 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),4,2,3,3,0,5,0,5,6,0,7,6,12,0,3,14,5,3,17,11,2,15,2,23,7,9,13,3,2,20,4,1,24,2,31,5,33,27,29,30
Sun Feb 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),6,1,1,3,0,0,4,4,0,6,9,6,12,14,12,4,4,3,5,18,7,20,8,6,13,27,22,21,4,12,3,8,8,7,19,18,15,8,29,3
Mon Feb 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),8,2,1,3,3,8,3,6,2,7,5,8,11,7,15,14,11,19,20,3,19,13,20,1,16,21,10,10,5,15,22,14,31,11,25,24,15,23,11,17
Tue Feb 04 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),10,2,5,5,4,6,3,11,6,2,0,13,13,10,13,4,5,1,8,5,13,3,25,13,9,17,30,21,27,10,6,15,3,2,29,19,14,16,13,38
Wed Feb 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),12,1,4,2,8,4,5,3,6,7,8,14,17,18,9,13,21,8,10,5,17,2,7,12,14,15,29,5,17,10,16,8,8,6,22,20,23,8,41,35
Mon Feb 10 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),14,9,8,2,14,14,1,11,4,0,2,12,13,13,2,12,23,8,28,14,1,23,18,33,33,7,17,12,16,21,24,5,20,12,29,39,3,28,28,26
Wed Feb 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),16,7,14,12,16,17,10,17,20,9,21,3,5,25,23,5,8,25,9,21,6,25,8,15,24,22,12,33,25,35,4,27,21,13,24,5,37,37,14,4
Sat Feb 08 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),18,6,7,6,8,1,5,11,13,2,13,3,1,5,21,9,24,20,14,19,5,4,0,23,27,5,13,7,17,10,9,28,24,1,29,28,42,18,28,14
Sun Feb 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),20,8,2,0,2,7,2,7,2,14,17,2,2,2,7,2,18,1,14,7,4,6,25,4,10,17,34,36,2,19,13,27,22,23,36,3,16,42,7,16
Mon Feb 10 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),14,9,8,2,14,14,1,11,4,0,2,12,13,13,2,12,23,8,28,14,1,23,18,33,33,7,17,12,16,21,24,5,20,12,29,39,3,28,28,26
Tue Feb 11 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),24,7,6,12,7,14,5,1,14,1,14,8,2,15,0,25,2,0,2,25,6,24,18,26,8,10,25,21,33,10,27,15,33,30,36,39,38,15,46,9
Wed Feb 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),16,7,14,12,16,17,10,17,20,9,21,3,5,25,23,5,8,25,9,21,6,25,8,15,24,22,12,33,25,35,4,27,21,13,24,5,37,37,14,4
Thu Feb 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),28,5,13,15,13,4,5,1,14,0,17,6,18,17,19,4,6,22,21,30,15,6,11,34,10,32,19,20,29,16,32,42,38,26,37,19,20,4,38,25
Fri Feb 14 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),30,5,12,13,1,1,7,13,19,13,3,17,4,16,15,14,6,11,12,11,0,11,33,28,4,13,1,2,22,4,40,37,24,27,41,19,22,19,8,24
Sat Feb 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),32,15,12,10,5,15,8,21,6,2,0,9,8,0,28,21,26,13,9,30,3,17,6,8,14,28,36,28,30,41,26,46,36,22,13,39,5,10,21,12
Sun Feb 16 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),34,10,6,3,1,17,18,11,19,8,9,7,20,20,18,27,21,30,25,12,10,25,14,37,20,32,15,10,23,5,3,0,48,13,26,14,6,39,34,27
Mon Feb 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),36,15,7,19,5,15,17,20,4,19,22,15,24,19,29,3,21,15,12,23,14,11,32,14,10,39,31,24,45,37,29,3,15,22,44,52,52,38,7,47
Tue Feb 18 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),38,3,0,21,18,19,21,2,1,10,6,15,5,7,29,12,16,28,31,8,5,30,36,1,35,28,8,21,1,9,33,32,24,22,34,51,25,12,36,9
Wed Feb 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),40,6,13,3,19,0,18,8,10,25,6,19,27,8,7,15,35,32,2,25,21,3,25,38,20,12,31,20,6,4,5,49,29,37,50,22,51,21,1,13
```

Image of Final Dashboard:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Cooper. but the values in Column B are not dates but numbers.

Comment: I think that should do it.